# Cannot create checkpoint on Hyper-V (0x800423F4)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

**Host Machine:**

- Intel Core i3 3120M @ 2,50Ghz 2,50Ghz
- 12GB RAM
- Windows 10 Enterprise 64Bit
- 750GB HD
- 250GB SSD

**Virtual Machine:**

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
- 4 virtual processors
- 8GB RAM

I'm having some problems to create checkpoints on my VM. When i try to do it, Hyper-V goes until 19% of the creating progress, and then this error screen appears:

[image: Error1]

I've analyzed Event Viewer's logs, and on the **Hyper-V Worker > Admin** section, it shows the following messages:

> 'PNSP2013' could not initiate a checkpoint operation: %%2147754996 (0x800423F4). (Virtual machine ID 69EAA8C6-E8E9-4585-97AE-5633F400BB89)[

And I also collected VSSDiag's log, which contains no relevant information (at least for me)

> A VSS writer has rejected an event with error 0x800423f4, The writer experienced a non-transient error.  If the backup process is retried,
>   the error is likely to reoccur.
>   Changes that the writer made to the writer components while handling the event will not be available to the requester.
>   Check the event log for related events from the application hosting the VSS writer.
>   Log:
>
> ```
> Operation:    PostSnapshot  Event
> Context:
> Execution Context: Writer
> Writer Class Id: {b2014c9e-8711-4c5c-a5a9-3cf384484757}
> Writer Name: NTDS 
> Writer Instance ID: {2b09511a-25fd-47cd-929f-4f1f60cc1594}
> Command Line: C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe
> Process ID: 636NTDS
> ```

Some important points to consider:

1. I have enough space on the SSD drive to store the checkpoint file.
2. I've tried to stop all non-Microsoft services on the VM and restart it, but no success
3. If i turn off the VM, the checkpoint can be created with no errors.
4. According to [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-backup-fail-vss-non-retryable-error-for/d5b5639e-059f-4d55-a0fd-fd64c02f0b04?auth=1), i've also checked the KB982018, and it's already installed on the VM.

I can't figure out what the hell is going on... Some help?

Comment: Is the Server VM a Domain Controller?  If you run `vssadmin list writers` in the VM, what does it report for the NTDS VSS writer's 'State' and 'Last Error'?  What does `automount` run from within `diskpart` report?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, it is a Domain Controller. About the vssadmin, when i try to make the checkpoint, the NTDS  says: Failed on the State and "Non retryable error" on the "Last Error". When i run diskpart then automount, it says: "automatic mounting of new volumes enabled"

Comment: Just to make sure, have you tried rebooting the host?   Also, in the registry at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` do any of the listed profiles end with `.bak`?  Also you say you have enough space to store the snapshot, but exactly how big is the VM and how much space do you actually have free on the host's system drive?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, i've already rebooted, and no way. After rebooting, all VSS writers went to Stable state (including NTDS) but when i try to make the ckeckpoint, the error occurs again. About the registry key, no profiles are listed with .bak

Comment: Have you got SQL server installed on there as well (helpfully not, it's a DC, but you never know ;) )? If you spin up a new VM, and install Server 2008 R2 (and nothing further). does it exhibit the same problem?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, i have (it is an internal VM configured with a specific environment (Sharepoint 2013 and a bunch of other things). About the clean VM, i am unable to get a new WS2008R2 right now. But i've noticed something strange. If i stop the `AD Domain Services` service (it also stops the `DFS Replication`, `DNS Server`, `Kerberos Key Distribution Center` and `Intersite Messaging`), the checkpoint is created successfully. Is it a clue?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've tracked that only the `AD Domain Services` cause the problem. I've tried to stop each of the services mentioned above separately, and the problem still occurred. When i stopped ADDS, the checkpoint was created. Is there something i can do in AD to track more specifically the problem?

Comment: NTDS is the "NT Directory Service" which is the AD stuff, so yeah it makes sense that disabling the AD stuff prevents the NTDS writer form having a problem.  Back to SQL, re-enable everything AD, open up Services.msc and disable the SQL VSS Writer service, and try the snapshot again. Also, have you ensured all updates, rollup packs, service packs, etc., for Windows, SQL, SharePoint, etc. have been installed?

Comment: Also check the VM's Event Logs for VSS timeout events: Event ID: 12290, 2004, and/or 25 (relating to VolSnap).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Did the SQL VSS Writer disabling. Snapshot failed. About the updates and related: yes, it is everything OK.

I've noticed that this error jumped up on Event viewer: `lsass (644) An attempt to open the file "\\?\Volume{abd87a7b-a025-11e3-bc41-806e6f6e6963}\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit" for read only access failed with system error 32 (0x00000020): "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ".  The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).`

Comment: About the VSS Timeout, i didn't noticed anything about it... Do i need to look in some specific place on eventvwr?

Comment: Did you move or copy the virtual machine folder at some point? I'm guessing that if you did, you did not reset the folder permissions, which would prevent the machine from saving a snapshot. In particular, each VM has its own service account, and requires full permissions on relevant files: e.g. VHDs, VM folder, etc.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Hello @InteXX, i'm sorry. No solution until now. What i've done to temporarily fix this, is disabling AD Domain Services (in my case, disabling the service is not a problem).

Comment: Thanks for the update—see my answer. Give it a try, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue for pre-2016 DCs running in VMs on 2016/Win10 Hypervisors.

The problem is the new Production Checkpoint architecture. If you change the Checkpoint type to Standard in the VM's settings, the Checkpoint will succeed.

Comment: Damn dude, you're a freaking genius! Thank you SO much for this.

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos — Not really... I just happened to stumble onto the answer, that's all. And spent a day futzing with it. But thanks :-)

Comment: You've just saved me hours of wasted time, thank you so much.

Comment: @Basic: How do you know it was hours if you didn't waste it? ;-)

Comment: @InteXX Because I wouldn't have started looking there. I thought ti was an issue with Shadow Copy on the volume itself, eg a disk issue.

Comment: @Basic: Sounds good to me  :-)

Answer (score 1):

What ended up fixing it for me.
Navigate to folder containing the Hyper-V VHD files.
Go to folder Properties>Security>Edit
Add INTERACTIVE and SERVICE and give them Full control.
Checkpoints of running VMs now run without error

Comment: Thank you for this, it works. I was already using standard checkpoints, so the accepted answer wasn't right for me. My issue arose after I changed the size of the vhd. It all worked well during that day, then I shut down the VM and the computer and the next day when trying to start the VM, all of a sudden it threw that error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and none of the above worked.
I found this solution elsewhere on the internet, which did work.

```
icacls C:\YourPath\YourVMFolder /grant “NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines”:F /T
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I fixed this issue with a brand new setup with Hyper-V 2019 and Veeam 10.

The issue I was having was that the backup and checkpoint would get to 7% or 50% and freeze. The backup job froze, then VM guests froze. I was not able to gracefully shut down the VM guests. When I tried to reboot the Hyper-V host, it froze.

- New Dell PowerEdge Server stand alone server.
- New Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V (stand alone)
- 3 x New Windows Server 2019 VM guests
- 1 x New Ubuntu 20.04 Server VM guest
- Veeam Backup & Replication 10.0 Community Edition.

After changing the checkpoint type to Standard in the VM's settings in Hyper-V manager, then rebooted all VM guests and VM host, I ran the backup again and the checkpoint succeeded in a few seconds and the backup ran without any problems.