# Windows 10 - Hyper-V - Cannot create the checkpoint and '' failed to change state

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v

I have a peculiar problem on a `Windows 10 Enterprise N` machine. A VM that starts without a problem on two `Windows 10 Pro` laptops wont start. The first error I get is this:

[image]

Looking at the thread [Cannot create checkpoint on Hyper-V (0x800423F4)](https://superuser.com/questions/1070464/cannot-create-checkpoint-on-hyper-v-0x800423f4) I have verified that `Standard Checkpoints` are used. If I Disable checkpoints I get the error `'' failed to change state`.

[image]

[image]

Working configuration on `Windows 10 Pro` computer:

[image]

I have tested the `.vhd` file that won't work on the `Windows 10 Enterprise N` machine and it starts fine from a `Windows 10 Pro` computer. Both Windows computers file system is `NTFS` and the portable drive which contains the `.vhd` file is `exFAT`.

Looking at `Event Viewer -> Application and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Hyper-V-VMMS -> Admin` and `Hyper-V-Worker -> Admin`

The event looks like this for Checkpoint operation failed:

> The description for Event ID 16370 from source
>   Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS cannot be found. Either the component
>   that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the
>   installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on
>   the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> OldVM
>
> B9EE18D2-ED58-4690-9D45-3E46E1B13EC5
>
> E:\disk.vhd
>
> %%2147943065
>
> 0x80070299
>
> The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present

Like this for failed to change state:

> The description for Event ID 12010 from source
>   Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker cannot be found. Either the component
>   that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the
>   installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on
>   the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> OldVM
>
> B9EE18D2-ED58-4690-9D45-3E46E1B13EC5
>
> Microsoft Emulated IDE Controller
>
> %%2147943065
>
> 0x80070299
>
> 83F8638B-8DCA-4152-9EDA-2CA8B33039B4
>
> The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present

The error `0x80070299` could be a defragment issue but the drive is optimized automatically.

[image]

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69a4fb7c-ddd7-4b84-bf8b-977d86771d5d/error-0x80070299-the-requested-operation-could-not-be-completed-due-to-a-file-system-limitation?forum=winserverfiles

Both the working machine and non working has Partition style: GUID Partition Table (GPT) and the non working machine has 84,5 GB free space and the total VM disk size is 72,0 GB. When it is started on the other machine disk space is not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

- Check in the Event Viewer, section
  *Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Hyper-V-Worker*,
  errors marked "Admin" or "Error", for the cause of the problem
- The exFAT disk might be unsuitable and should be formatted as NTFS
  (see last entry in [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/09c6ded2-9a5e-4002-b4f8-f386ba796a18/failed-to-start-new-vm-with-existing-vhdx-failed-to-change-state?forum=winserverhyperv))
- Update Integration Services
- Check resources : Memory and disk space for host and guest
- Check the state of the network adapter, mounted ISO and try disabling the antivirus.

Comment: Updated with event viewer. True for `exFAT` but it works on the other machine while using the portable hard drive as well. Memory and disk space is OK. Tried with disabled network adapter/ antivirus but it was still the same result. What do you mean with mounted ISO? The `.vhd` works on one machine but not on the other. Tried disabling all Integration Services but the result was the same. I can create new files on the hard drive.

Comment: (1) Event ID 16370 means "FileServer cannot create the storage required for the checkpoint" and this has to do with `E:\disk.vhd `. Check *all* free disk space required by the VM definition. (2) Event ID 12010 means "Failed to Power on with Error A device attached to the system is not functioning" and on the Microsoft Emulated IDE Controller it means bad defined disk or CD.

Comment: Can't say exactly why it did not work on one machine but when I copied the VM to an internal hard drive everything started working. Thanks for your help!